# Почему не работает команда run code в vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

С момента установки `vscode` на комп не работает возможность видеть результат работы кода во встроенной консоли. Я выделяю участок кода, жму правой кнопкой мыши, выбираю run code и ничего не происходит. В консоли пусто.
Что не так? Как решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не совпадение. Я попробовала, и у меня тоже всё заработало, когда открыла через папку, а не просто файл.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Все заработало. Файл script.js я открывал с помощью Open file..., а когда открыл через Open folder... и уже в папке выбирал интересующий файл - все отработало как надо. Может не в этом дело, но это единственное, что я сделал для решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Разверну ответ немного шире.

Да, действительно есть разница, что использовать `Open File` или `Open Folder`.

При использовании `Open File` открывается только файл на редактирование и настройки для `VSCode` загружаются только для сущности `User`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же использовать `Open Folder`, то также загружаются настройки для рабочей области `Workspace`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдержка из [документации](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)

> You don't have to do anything for a folder to become a VS Code workspace other than open the folder with VS Code. Once a folder has been opened, VS Code will automatically keep track of things such as your open files and editor layout so the editor will be as you left it when you reopen that folder. You can also add other folder-specific configurations such as workspace-specific settings (versus global user settings), task definitions, and debugging launch files (see below in the workspace settings section).
>
> > **Перевод**
> > Вам не нужно ничего делать, для того чтобы папка стала рабочей областью, кроме того чтобы открыть папку в VSCode. Как только папка будет открыта, VSCode будет автоматически отслеживать такие вещи, как открытые файлы и лэйаут редактора, следовательно редактор будет таким, каким вы его оставили, когда вы снова ее откроете. Вы также можете добавить другие конфигурации для конкретных папок, такие как настройки для конкретной рабочей области (по сравнению с глобальными настройками пользователя), определения задач и файлы запуска отладки.